# Is it safe for different nginx servers to share logs?

Tags: nginx

I have two `server` blocks with the same server name in `nginx.conf`. One for http and the other for https. Since they are basically the same thing, I want to log the same file. Is it safe to write like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    access_log access.log;
    error_log error.log;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    access_log access.log;
    error_log error.log;
}
```

My concern is that simultaneous writes from the two servers may result in a garbled, interleaved log. Can this ever happen?

Edit. Logging from different sources is interleaved by nature. What I mean here is different texts interleaved within the same line, or write failure, or any other kinds of conflicts which make the log invalid.

Comment: There's just one server.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Hi what do you mean by this? They listen on different ports with different schemes and can possibly serve different contents, use different authentication, etc.

Comment: They are different for clients, but actually it's one nginx listening to several ports. It has no problem to write logs to one file.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Depending on configuration it can be one nginx master process with several worker processes and I think the log is written by the worker processes? If so then why it isn't possible for concurrent logging from different worker processes to conflict with each other? Do these worker processes use any forms of synchronization?

Comment: Nginx takes care of it. Thousands of nginx's installation write all logs into one file and have no problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There will be no problem as long as only one process try to write to one file.

If you configure two different nginx process to writing same file, then you will see interleaved texts in your log. but not in one process, even with multiple host config.

Comment: I think I know what you mean here. The whole thing is complicated by the fact that one nginx instance may have multiple processes. But from your answer and comments above it looks nginx takes care of logging from different processes as long as they belong to the same nginx instance.